# How do I know if my plants are already fully grown in Plants vs Zombies?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I still need to buy some upgrades, so I want to sell some of my plants from my Zen Garden when they are fully grown.

But how do I know when they are fully grown?

[Attributes to Randell](http://gamersqna.com/questions/74/in-plants-vs-zombies-how-do-i-know-if-my-plants-are-already-fully-grown)

Comment: you really want zombie hints from my gf? :)

Comment: I'm ambivalent as to whether it's ok to copy questions like that (even linking them)... shouldn't we wait for them to be asked organically? Or are you really interested in an answer?

Comment: I'm actually interested @Juan Plants vs Zombies rocks ;-)

Comment: ok, fair enough (and I agree, the other day a friend of mine showed it to me in his iPhone... very entertaining)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each "day" period they should require fewer things to become happy, and fully grown happy plants have a sort of glowing aura that's visible.

Comment: I think feeding the plant fertilizer 3 times means they are fully grown.

Answer (score 1):

a fully grown plant is one that you can sell for 7500 for most plants, 10000 for nighttime and pooltime plants and 3k for daisies

you know you can sell a plant if when you fertilize it it give diamond(s), if it wants bug spray or if it wants to listen to music